# Android ScrollView doesn't scroll to bottom

Tags: android, scrollview

This is part of my Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorGrey20"
        tools:context=".View.Activities.MainActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dip"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

...
```

My ScrollView doesn't scroll to bottom

[image: Screenshot]

The last icon and description are never reached.
What would I change in my layout?

Answer (score 2):

use

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

instead of `"wrap_content"`
in your ScrollView

Answer (score 2):

Use paddings instead of margins on scrollview and its subviews and scrolling will be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/scrollview"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll">
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had good results replacing

```xml
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

...with this:

```xml
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

(I still have problems understanding the root cause.)